# Add custom style formats to TinyMCE (Advanced Custom Fields)

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a new TinyMCE layout for Advanced Custom Fields called "Very Simple" that I want to use on specific WYSIWYG fields. I've managed to add the buttons I want and I'm now looking for a way to add a list of custom style formats as a dropdown, but I can't really figure out how to do this.

The code I have right now is the following:

```
// Customize ACF MCE
add_filter( 'acf/fields/wysiwyg/toolbars' , 'new_toolbars'  );
function new_toolbars( $toolbars )
{
    // - this toolbar has only 1 row of buttons
    $toolbars['Very Simple' ] = array();
    $toolbars['Very Simple' ][1] = array('bold' , 'italic' , 'underline', 'link', 'unlink' );

    $style_formats = array(  
        // These are the custom styles
        array(  
            'title' => 'Red Button',  
            'block' => 'span',  
            'classes' => 'red-button',
            'wrapper' => true,
        ),  
        array(  
            'title' => 'Content Block',  
            'block' => 'span',  
            'classes' => 'content-block',
            'wrapper' => true,
        ),
        array(  
            'title' => 'Highlighter',  
            'block' => 'span',  
            'classes' => 'highlighter',
            'wrapper' => true,
        ),
    );  
    // Insert the array, JSON ENCODED, into 'style_formats'
    $toolbars['Very Simple'][1]['styleselect'] = json_encode( $style_formats );

    // return $toolbars - IMPORTANT!
    return $toolbars;
}
```

The style format dropdown is not showing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

The `styleselect` dropdown is hidden by default, so to get any registered formats/styles will show, you'll just need to activate the `styleselect` dropdown menu in the Visual editor.

The below function (from the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles)) filters the array of buttons loaded by TinyMCE, so just add this to your `functions.php`. I'm using the `mce_buttons_2` filter to make it appear in the second row of my toolbar.

```
// Callback function to insert 'styleselect' into the $buttons array
function my_mce_buttons_2( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}

// Register our callback to the appropriate filter
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'my_mce_buttons_2' );
```